# How to filter based on compared values of fields in a model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

How to filter queryset based on comparing internal values of fields in any model?

For instance, have a look at the example below:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    num1 = models.IntegerField()
    num2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Say I have to filter for the Model1 values for which num2 - num1 is less than 10.
So, how will we write the filter condition?
That is `Model1.objects.filter(???)`?

Also, say the fields are datetime, as below:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    t1 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    t2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can we implement a similar case as above. Say we want to filter based upon t2-t1 less than 10 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the calculation and then filter on the result.

```
from django.db.models import F
Model1.objects.annotate(diff=F('num1')-F('num2')).filter(diff__lt=10)
```